# How to find the minimum using algebraic query language

Tags: database, algebraic-data-types

I need to find the cheapest Honda Civic sold in this table

```
Sell(DName, Make, ModelNum, Price)
```

There are other tables, but I am assuming that no other manufacturers have named their make Civic.

So I'm looking to find the lowest price that is of Make Civic. But how exactly do I find the lowest price? I would know if there was a set price (`SELECT the make WHEN price < "x amount"`), but how about to I go do find the lowest price in the table.

Comment: Which Database are you using? What is the type of Price?

Answer (score 0):

Select min(price) from Sell where DName='Civic'